# can anyone explain stack ,queue,linked list in java with programs for each?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue

I am new to java and as well as i didn't know any other language apart from java oops concept.i am  newbie to programming.so for me  easy to understand, can anyone explain stack ,queue,linked list in java with programs for each?

Answer (score 2):

A Stack is an abstract data type or collection where in Push,the addition of data elements to the collection, and Pop, the removal of data elements from the collection, are the major operations performed on the collection. The Push and Pop operations are performed only at one end of the Stack which is referred to as the 'top of the stack'.

In other words,a Stack can be simply defined as Last In First Out (LIFO) data structure,i.e.,the last element added at the top of the stack(In) should be the first element to be removed(Out) from the stack.

```
// Demonstrate the Stack class.
import java.util.*;
class StackDemo {
static void showpush(Stack st, int a) {
st.push(new Integer(a));
System.out.println("push(" + a + ")");
System.out.println("stack: " + st);
}
static void showpop(Stack st) {
System.out.print("pop -> ");
Integer a = (Integer) st.pop();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println("stack: " + st);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
Stack st = new Stack();
System.out.println("stack: " + st);
showpush(st, 42);
showpush(st, 66);
showpush(st, 99);
showpop(st);
showpop(st);
showpop(st);
try {
showpop(st);
} catch (EmptyStackException e) {
System.out.println("empty stack");
}
}
}
```

for more detail about Stack you can see [this official link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Queue:
A queue supports the insert and remove operations using a first-in first-out (FIFO) discipline

For more detail: [Queue](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-interface-java/)

Linked List:
Java LinkedList class uses doubly linked list to store the elements. It provides a linked-list data structure. It inherits the AbstractList class and implements List and Deque interfaces.
For more detail:
[official link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and another
[This link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/)

[geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/) is better for the beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Consider starting by looking at the official [**Java Platform Documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/):

**[Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):**

> The Stack class represents a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack of
>   objects. It extends class Vector with five operations that allow a
>   vector to be treated as a stack. The usual push and pop operations are
>   provided, as well as a method to peek at the top item on the stack, a
>   method to test for whether the stack is empty, and a method to search
>   the stack for an item and discover how far it is from the top.
>
> When a stack is first created, it contains no items.
>
> **...**

**[Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)**:

> A collection designed for holding elements prior to processing.
>   Besides basic Collection operations, queues provide additional
>   insertion, extraction, and inspection operations. Each of these
>   methods exists in two forms: one throws an exception if the operation
>   fails, the other returns a special value (either null or false,
>   depending on the operation). The latter form of the insert operation
>   is designed specifically for use with capacity-restricted Queue
>   implementations; in most implementations, insert operations cannot
>   fail
>
> **...**

**[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)**:

> Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces.
>   Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements
>   (including null).
>
> All of the operations perform as could be expected
>   for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will
>   traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer
>   to the specified index.
>
> **...**

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented array base stack and  queue .Code can be available in [github](https://github.com/gatisahu/common-util/tree/master/src/main/java/com/gati/common/collection)  location and 
[junit](https://github.com/gatisahu/common-util/tree/master/src/test/java/com/gati/common/collection)